# Cryptic "Access is Denied" exception from WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a secure WCF service with custom authentication. When I am stress testing it - having a few dozens of clients connect at the same time, I often get the following exception in my server-side logs:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Access is denied.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AuthorizationBehavior.Authorize(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I've enabled tracing through System.Diagnostics but that only got me a longer stack trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AuthorizationBehavior.Authorize(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext securityContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback
```

Why is this happening and how can I find out more about what's going wrong here?

Thanks,
urig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "custom authentication" and "[when] a few dozens of clients connect at the same time" I would guess that your custom authentication (from the stack trace: the authorization part) is not fully thread-safe. It could be that any error in the authorization part is (mis-)diagnosed as an "Access denied" error.

There might be some more information in the InnerException properties. But otherwise, maybe you can post some details of your own authorization code.

Comment: Thanks Henk. That's a good analysis. I'm in the process of adding more logging to my custom authentication and will update later. How can I access the innerException through code / logging? It's WCF that's throwing the FaultException so where would you put a catch clause for it?

Answer (score 3):

Still haven't fixed the problem but I'm sure it's indeed within my own custom authentication mechanism - so I'm accepting Henk's answer.

For me, the smoking gun was found when I added diagnostics for System.IdentityModel like so:

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.IdentityModel" switchValue="All">
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add name="IdentityModelListener">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add initializeData="C:\Tracing\App_identitymodellog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             name="IdentityModelListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp, Callstack">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
    </system.diagnostics>
```

and in the resulting traces saw this:

> System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache.get_Callstack()
>   System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener.WriteFooter(TraceEventCache
>   eventCache)
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceData(TraceEventType
>   eventType, Int32 id, Object data)
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType
>   type, TraceCode code, String
>   description, TraceRecord trace,
>   Exception exception, Object source)
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType
>   type, TraceCode code, String
>   description)
>   System.IdentityModel.SecurityUtils.CreateDefaultAuthorizationContext(IList`1
>   authorizationPolicies)
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.get_AuthorizationContext()
>   Foo.Bar..Core.Security.SessionAuthorizationManager.CheckClaimSet(OperationContext
>   operationContext) in ...
>   Foo.Bar..Core.Security.SessionAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess(OperationContext
>   operationContext, Message& message) in
>   ...
>   **> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AuthorizationBehavior.Authorize(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)**
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext
>   request, Boolean cleanThread,
>   OperationContext
>   currentOperationContext)
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext
>   request, OperationContext
>   currentOperationContext)
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
>   System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext
>   securityContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object
>   state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes,
>   NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 bytesRead,
>   NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes,
>   NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

The very next call after Dispatcher.AuthorizationBehavior.Authorize() is to my own implementation of AuthorizationManager. That is most probably where the problem comes from. The Authorize() method merely throws the FaultException as a result.

Comment: this comment  help me on some inherited code base
" own implementation of AuthorizationManager"